# NullPointerException at doing Session.load() while first time trying out Neo4J OGM

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am trying out Neo4J OGM for first time from simple example given on its [github page](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm) and with the help of its [manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/#tutorial).

I am running `neo4j-community-3.0.0-M05`.

I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.lookup(LoadOneDelegate.java:56)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Capability$LoadOne$load.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at Main.main(Main.groovy:24)
```

The exception occurs on line 24 of `Main.groovy`. I debugged. It occurs on `session.load()` call.

I feel that this must be beacuse I must have made some mistake in setting up dependencies. But cant figure it out.

This is my code:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mahesha999.exp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Neo4JTemp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>      
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>    
</project>
```

**ogm.properties**

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver
URI=http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474
```

**Actor.groovy**

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId

@NodeEntity
public class Actor {    
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "ACTS_IN", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

    public Actor() { }

    public Actor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void actsIn(Movie movie) {
        movies<< movie;
        movie.getActors() << this;
    }
}
```

**Movie.groovy**

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId

@NodeEntity
public class Movie {    
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private int released;

    @Relationship(type = "ACTS_IN", direction = "INCOMING")
    List<Actor> actors = [];

    public Movie() {}

    public Movie(String title, int year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.released = year;
    }    
}
```

**Main.groovy**

```
1    import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session
2    import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory
3    
4    class Main {
5       
6       static main(def args)
7       {
8           //Set up the Session
9           SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("movies.domain");
10          Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
11          
12          Movie movie = new Movie("The Matrix", 1999);
13          
14          Actor keanu = new Actor("Keanu Reeves");
15          keanu.actsIn(movie);
16          
17          Actor carrie = new Actor("Carrie-Ann Moss");
18          carrie.actsIn(movie);
19      
20          //Persist the movie. This persists the actors as well.
21          session.save(movie);
22                  
23          //Load a movie
24          Movie matrix = session.load(Movie.class, movie.id);
25          for(Actor actor : matrix.getActors()) {
26              System.out.println("Actor: " + actor.name);
27          }
28      }   
29    }
```

Comment: Which version of the OGM do you use? I cannot reproduce this with 2.0.4

Comment: shouldnt it be `2.0.4` as specified in `pom.xml`? btw is it working for you? in debugging mode, on line 21 of `Main.groovy`, session is not `null`.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. Yes I used your pom.xml, and it works fine for me. What I did not see is your packages for Actor and Movie- they're in movies.domain right?

Comment: aaahhh missed that. Skimmed thru OGM manual, primarily going thru  code (no explanation, its a bit huge :p) & no code had `package movies.domain;` at top. Was wondering whats that parameter to `SessionFactory` constructor. API said it correctly:`SessionFactory(String... packages)`. But that too did not made sense. My bad...new to Spring too to click me that it must be to load beans / config from. Was primarily .NET developer. Anyways, billion thanks for trying out my code & pin pointing issue. Btn are their any more tuts about OGM, may be more step by step?

Comment: Will add some resources to my answer, please accept! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package being scanned (movies.domain) does not seem to contain your entity classes. That's why the entity is not saved, and the id is null.

The OGM reference guide (with tutorial) is here: http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/

And a small sample app: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-ogm-university/tree/2.0